# Select data then add to database

Tags: php

I want to select songID from table **song**  then I add data to the database like this:

> $add_song_cmd = "INSERT INTO `song`(`name`,`genreID`,`artistID`,`file`) VALUES ('$song_name', '$genreID','$artistID', '../layout/audio/$filename')";

How can I do this?

My upload.php below:

> upload - vnmusic 
>           
>       
>       
>       
>       
>               
>                   
>               
>               
>                   
>                        đăng nhập |  đăng ký

```
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social/youtube.png" alt="youtube" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/social/rss.png" alt="rss feed" /></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<!--header.close --> 

    <div style="clear: both"></div>
<!--navbar.open --> 
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="navbar-menu-link">
            <ul>

                <li><a href="home.html">trang chủ</a></li>
                <li><a href="top-song.html">bài hát</a></li><!-- chưa xây dựng -->
                <li><a href="playlist.html">playlist</a></li>
                <li><a href="artist.html">nghệ sĩ</a></li>
                <li><a href="genre.html">thể loại</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">giới thiệu</a></li> 

                <li><a href="upload.html"><font color="#f1c40f">upload</a></font></li> 


            </ul>     
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-search">
            <div id="navbar-search-content">
                <input type="text" name="navbar-search-textbox" size="30" />
                <input type="submit" name="navbar-search-submit" value=" tìm kiếm" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
<!--navbar.close -->
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<!--main.open --> 
    <div id="main">
        <div id="main-content">
            <h1>upload lên vnmusic</h1>
            <div id="main-content-upload">

                <div id="main-content-browser">
                <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                tên bài hát(*): <input type="text" name="song_name"> 
                tên nghệ sĩ(*): <input type="text" name="artist_name"> 
                <p>
                thể loại (*):
                <select name="genreID">
                <option value="1">Nhạc Vàng</option>
                <option value="2">Nhạc Đỏ</option>
                <option value="3">Hòa Tấu Dân Tộc</option>
                <option value="4">Beat & Instrumental</option>
                <option value="5">Nhạc Trẻ</option>
                <option value="6">Nhạc Dance</option>
                <option value="7">Hiphop & RAP</option>
                <option value="8">Nhạc Đám Cưới</option>
                <option value="9">Hòa Tấu Piano</option>
                <option value="10">Hòa Tấu Guitar</option>
                <option value="11">Hòa tấu Violin</option>
                <option value="12">Nhạc Trữ Tình</option>
                <option value="13">Nhạc Về Cha Mẹ</option>
                <option value="14">Jazz & Blue</option>
                <option value="15">Dân Ca</option>
                <option value="16">Nhạc Của Tui</option>
                <option value="17" selected>Chưa Phân Loại</option>
                </select>



                <p>
                duyệt tìm bài hát(*):
                <input type="file" name="myFile" id="fileToUpload" accept=".mp3"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="tải bài hát lên" name="post_song">
                </form>
                </div>


                <!--@php main -->
                <?php
                require_once('connect.php');
                if (isset($_POST['post_song']))
                {
                $song_name = $_POST['song_name'];
                $artist_name = $_POST['artist_name'];
                $genreID = $_POST['genreID'];
                    // kiểm tra tên artist đã có trong db chưa
                    if($artist_name == "" or $song_name == "")
                    {
                    echo" <h3>Mời nhập đầy đủ thông tin về bài hát! </h3>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $check_exist_artist_cmd = "SELECT * FROM artist where name = '$artist_name'";
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$check_exist_artist_cmd);
                        $check = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
                        if($check == 0){ 
                            $genreID = $_POST['genreID'];
                            $add_artist_cmd = "INSERT INTO `artist`(`name`,`genreID`) VALUES ('$artist_name', '$genreID')";
                            mysqli_query($conn,$add_artist_cmd); 
                            // chèn artist -> get ID -> chèn bài hát
                            $artistID_select = "SELECT artistID FROM artist where name = '$artist_name'";   // lấy ID từ tên artist
                            $query = mysqli_query($conn,$artistID_select); // chạy query
                            $check = mysqli_num_rows($query); // tạo biến để lấy số row
                            if($check == true){ // kiểm tra nếu dữ liệu đã đc chèn chưa
                                $get_artistID = mysqli_fetch_array($query); // gán mảng vào biến $get_artistID
                                $artistID = $get_artistID['artistID'];

                                //echo $artistID;

                                define("UPLOAD_DIR", "audio/");

                                if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
                                    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

                                    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                                        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
                                        exit;
                                    }

                                    // ensure a safe filename
                                    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

                                    // don't overwrite an existing file
                                    $i = 0;
                                    $parts = pathinfo($name);
                                    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
                                        $i++;
                                        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
                                    }

                                    // preserve file from temporary directory
                                    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
                                        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
                                    if (!$success) { 
                                        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
                                        exit;
                                    }

                                    // set proper permissions on the new file
                                    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
                                    $filename = $name;
                                    }

                                    $get_artistID = mysqli_fetch_array($query); // gán mảng vào biến $get_artistID
                                    $artistID = $get_artistID['artistID'];
                                    $add_song_cmd = "INSERT INTO `song`(`name`,`genreID`,`artistID`,`file`) VALUES ('$song_name', '$genreID','$artistID', '../layout/audio/$filename')"; 
                                    // lệnh insert dữ liệu vào bảng
                                    mysqli_query($conn,$add_song_cmd); // chạy lệnh thêm bài hát

                                    echo "Bài hát ".$song_name." của nghệ sĩ ".$artist_name." được upload thành công !";
                                    // lấy bài hát mới add vào là hiển thị ra link ... update sau


                            }


                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            // chèn bài hát
                            define("UPLOAD_DIR", "audio/");

                                if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
                                    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

                                    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                                        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
                                        exit;
                                    }

                                    // ensure a safe filename
                                    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

                                    // don't overwrite an existing file
                                    $i = 0;
                                    $parts = pathinfo($name);
                                    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
                                        $i++;
                                        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
                                    }

                                    // preserve file from temporary directory
                                    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
                                        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
                                    if (!$success) { 
                                        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
                                        exit;
                                    }

                                    // set proper permissions on the new file
                                    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
                                    $filename = $name;
                                    }

                                    $artistID_select = "SELECT artistID FROM artist where name = '$artist_name'";   // lấy ID từ tên artist
                                    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$artistID_select); // chạy query
                                    $get_artistID = mysqli_fetch_array($query); // gán mảng vào biến $get_artistID
                                    $artistID = $get_artistID['artistID'];
                                    $add_song_cmd = "INSERT INTO `song`(`name`,`genreID`,`artistID`,`file`) VALUES ('$song_name', '$genreID','$artistID', '../layout/audio/$filename')"; 
                                    // lệnh insert dữ liệu vào bảng
                                    mysqli_query($conn,$add_song_cmd); // chạy lệnh thêm bài hát
                                    echo "Bài hát ".$song_name." của nghệ sĩ ".$artist_name." được upload thành công !";
                                    // lấy bài hát mới add vào là hiển thị ra link ... update sau

                        }


                    }
                }

                ?>
                <!-- php main-->





            </div>

            <div id="main-content-upload-note">
                 <p>Hướng dẫn đăng / upload <p>

                1. Tài khoản đã đăng nhập thành công <br>

                2. File upload không quá 120MB <br>

                3. Định dạng file upload: *.mp3 <br>

                4. Bit rate 128kbs trở lên. <br>

                5. File upload sẽ được kiểm duyệt trong 48 giờ <br>

                <p>Quy định upload <p>

                Bài hát đăng tải vi phạm nội dung cấp trong "Thỏa thuận sử dụng" sẽ bị xóa khỏi hệ thống và tài khoản bị khóa vĩnh viễn <br>


            </div>


        </div>
        <div id="main-sidebar">
            <div id="main-sidebar-topten">
                <h3>bài hát đã upload</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">nhớ nhau hoài - đan nguyên</a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main-sidebar-ads">
                <h3>quảng cáo</h3>
                <div id="main-sidebar-ads-content">
                    <img src="images/ads/offline-nhac-cong.png" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
<!--main.close --> 
    <div style="clear: both"></div>

</div>

<!--footer.open --> 
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-tab">
            <div id="footer-tab1">
                <h3> Giới thiệu</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="footer-tab2">
                <h3> Liên kết</h3>

            </div>
            <div id="footer-tab3">
                <h3> Liên hệ</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="footer-tab4">
                <h3> Subscribe vnmusic</h3>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
<!--footer.close --> 
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please specify what is your issue here.? 
Have you tried anything what is the error you got?

Comment: @Murali .. Here is problem.

Comment: When user submit a song, this process will insert 4 information in to database, specific is table "song" will inserted: song name, artistID, genreID, file .. and songID is auto Increment.
I want show the song that just uploaded by the user.
-> I want to get songID of the song just upload by the user. I dont know how to perform this.